# (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Tags: php

I have got Parse error like this:

> syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING)

For below code line

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT license_parent_type_details.ParentTypeId,license_parent_type_details.TypeName FROM tenant.license_parent_type_details order by TypeName asc";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row_list = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
```

**For below code line**

```
echo '<option value="'.$row_list['ParentTypeId'].'">'<"'.($_POST['seltypes']==$row_list['ParentTypeId'] ? ' selected="selected" : '').'>'. $row_list['TypeName']."'</option>';
```

Comment: You should read up on strings and formatting, you will find your answer. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected version:

```
echo '<option value="', $row_list['ParentTypeId'], '"', ($_POST['seltypes']==$row_list['ParentTypeId'] ? ' selected="selected" ' : ''), '>', $row_list['TypeName'], '</option>';
```

Mistakes:

1. Missing single quote
2. Superfluous double quote

Finding the original position of those errors is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I got syntax error unexpected )

Comment: Your update is correct but I got value in dropdown like : <">B1.....  B1 is value

Comment: @Nithya See my second update, please.

Answer (score 0):

#### Corrected Coded.

```
echo '<'. ($_POST['seltypes'] == $row_list['ParentTypeId'] 
                                    ? ' selected="selected" '
                                    : '').'>'. $row_list['TypeName'] .'</option>';
```

- You forgot a `'` after `selected="selected"`
- You had an extra `"` after `$row_list['TypeName']`

---

#### Visual Aid of above.

Here's a visual. Look for `-->` and `<--`. The one is brackets is the one I removed.

```
echo '<'. ($_POST['seltypes'] == $row_list['ParentTypeId'] 
                                    ? ' selected="selected" --> ' <-- 
                                    : '').'>'. $row_list['TypeName'] --> (") <-- .'</option>';
```

Comment: You used the top one, right?

Comment: I'm not getting a syntax error with the top one (only an unassigned variable, as I haven't given `$row_list` a value)